# How to use Socket.IO in android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, socket.io

In my application i want use **`Socket.io`** and for this i add below library and write below codes.
But when run application and click on **button** not show me any event!
I used **kotlin** for write android application.

After click on `button`, should show me **socket** state in `textView`, but not show any state!

**Socket library :**

```
compile 'com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.5.2'
```

**My Codes:**

```
class SocketActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_socket)

        val opts = IO.Options()
        opts.query = "token=${Constants.BIDZILA_TOKEN}"
        var socket = IO.socket(Constants.BIDZILA_SOCKET, opts)

        btnSend.setOnClickListener {
            socket.connect()

            Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(
                { socket?.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT) {
                    Log.d("SocketLog", "==============================CONNECTED")
                    socket_stateTxt.text = socket.connected().toString()
                }?.on(Socket.EVENT_DISCONNECT) {
                    Log.d("SocketLog", "==============================OFF")
                    socket_stateTxt.text = socket.connected().toString()
                } },
                2000
            )
        }
    }
}
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: I'm not sure if `socket.connect()` is async, but you can't do network connections on the main thread in Android. Also did you add all relevant permissions in the manifest? Also instead of `Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed` you can just use `runOnUiThread`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm establishing the connection like this:

```
private var socket = IO.socket("<YOUR_URL>")
                socket.let {
                    it!!.connect()
                    .on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT) {
                        Log.d("SignallingClient", "Socket connected!!!!!")
                    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use it!!
Should be socket?.let {}